# Get Keyboard events back, after WebBrowser gets focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control

I have a situation where I would want to use WFP `WebBrowser`, but when the user presses a button *something* happens; however after `WebBrowser` gets focus, some keyboard and mouse events no longer fire in my app.

**To reproduce:** Create a new project, set XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ProblemKeyboard.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Height="177" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and let the codebehide override `OnKeyDown()` event.

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        //The above line causes browser to focus 
        //and as a consequence the OnKeyDown() handler 
        //doesn't get called again
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) MessageBox.Show("Yey!");
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Okay, understandably the user might want to type his Google query. But at some point I want to get control back. To this end, I've devised a button. When you click this button I want keyboard control to come back to the WPF app. But no matter what the button does, I can't get `OnKeyDown()` to fire again.

My particular restrictions allow `WebBrowser` to be destroyed at this point. I tried clearing its parent container, tried calling `Dispose()` and the garbage collector. Tried `Focus()`ing on things that have that functionality. Nothing seems to get control back.

I'd rather avoid solutions which create new `Window()` or something to that effect.

**EDIT**

I've found that putting a `TextBox` and making it focus gets me back focus! However I have no textboxes in my window, and adding one just for giggles seems counter-intuitive at best.

**EDIT 2**

Current temporary solution puts an invisible (well, kinda, it's just 0 by 0, `Visibility.Hidden`  doesn't work) `TextBox` - enables it, focuses it and disables it. Without disabling it first some keys are handled by `TextBox` instead of bubbling up to `KeyDown()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is reproducible for `Enter` key only and the fix is to use OnKeyUp() for `Enter` Key....

```
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }
```